# Background image hidden unless I shrink the page width

Tags: css, background

all. I'm trying to add a css rectangle with a slight opacity over a three-image rotating slideshow. I couldn't get that to work so I tried creating the rectangle as an image with a transparent background so the pictures would show through and then setting the image as the background for my div (it'll have horizontal navigation over it at some point). It's a splash page so the slideshow takes up the whole background and I want to have the strip of black run across the entire browser width. The problem is that the rectangular black strip is only showing when I drag my browser window significantly smaller.

Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Splash Page
*/
?>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

#slideshow {
position:fixed;
z-index:0;
}

#slideshow IMG {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:auto;
opacity:0.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
z-index:auto;
opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
z-index:auto;
}

#slideshow img {
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
img.bg {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;
}

.enter {
background: url('http://newmarketdvm.com/vsc/wp-content/themes/mono/images/splash-  nav.png') repeat-x;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 700px;
position: absolute;
z-index:5000;
width: 1000px;
height: 75px;
display: block;
}

.enter p {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:30px;
font-family: Helvetica;
line-height:125%;
z-index:auto;
position: relative;
float: left;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="slideshow">
<img class="active" src="http://newmarketdvm.com/vsc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/medical-team.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" />
<img src="http://newmarketdvm.com/vsc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/dog-running-grass.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
<img src="http://newmarketdvm.com/vsc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Hans-treadmill-2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
</div>
<div class="enter"><p>test text and navigation will be here</p></div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Duuuuude. Commas and periods, use them!

Comment: You haven't closed the `media` query CSS curly braces

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that you are only setting styles for elements when the browser window is quite narrow. E.g. the paragraph only appears when the browser window is less that 1024px, because of this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
  .enter p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  line-height: 125%;
  z-index: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

This may be because you forgot to close off the media query a bit higher in the page:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  img.bg {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -512px;
}
```

That's not closed off, so all the rules that follow are governed by it.